# Wrong architecture C++? Xcode 4.3

Tags: c++, xcode, architecture

I am building a Windows based project on my Mac. I have fixed a lot of the errors but when I go to compile it gives the following error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Timer::reset()", referenced from:
      Timer::Timer() in main.o
  "Log::Log()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in main.o
  "Log::~Log()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_1 in main.o
  "Render::initSDL(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "Log::writeError(char*, ...)", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "EntityManager::init(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "EntityManager::loadAssets()", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "Level::getBlockCount()", referenced from:
      EntityManager::getBlockCount()       in main.o
  "Level::getBombCount()", referenced from:
      EntityManager::getBombCount()       in main.o
  "Level::getItemCount()", referenced from:
      EntityManager::getItemCount()       in main.o
  "Render::renderElement(int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect*)", referenced from:
      renderScene()     in main.o
  "EntityManager::getElement(int, ElementType)", referenced from:
      renderScene()     in main.o
  "Render::finishRender()", referenced from:
      renderScene()     in main.o
  "EntityManager::update()", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "EntityManager::interpolate(double)", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am curious as to why it only referenced a few functions? Do these functions contain non Mac compatible contents?

For example:

```
int Level::getItemCount()
{
    return itemVec.size();
}
```

itemVec is a vector, just to be clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run into linker errors, it means that the compiler could find the **declaration** but the linker couldn't find the **definition**

I suppose you already know but just in case :

For a method, the declaration is only it's signature 
eg :

```
class foo 
{
    public:
        void bar(); 
}
```

That is the declaration of the method "void Foo::bar()", and it goes into a header file (.h, .hpp, ...)

Now the definition of this method contains the body as well. It must match the declaration. Same example :

```
void Foo::bar()
{
std::cout << "Hello, world !" << std::endl;
}
```

That is the definition of the method "void Foo::bar()", and it (generally) goes into a source file (.cpp,.cxx, ...)

In your case, the compiler finds the delcaration but the linker doesn't find the definition. You have therefore to find where Timer::reset() is defined and check that this place is available for the linker.

The most typical reason for that would be that Timer::reset() is defined in a cpp file and that file isn't included in your xcode project (Don't worry, that happens all the time if you don't have a good build configuration tool such as Premake, Cmake, or whatever ...)

In that case the symbol will be declared because you have somewhere, in your code #include  "timer.h" or something similar, but not defined because the matching cpp isn't included in your project. It (probably) exists on your hard drive but it's not referenced in your project.

To solve this :

1. Look up where Timer::reset is defined
2. If it's not defined anywherem then you just found your problem. It has to be defined if it's called
3. If it's defined, then check that the cpp is included in your project, **in the same module as main.cpp**

You mention that it happens only for specific functions. I might add that if a function is never called you won't get the error.  Do you have this error message only with the functions which are actually called in main.cpp ?

For more details :

As far as I know (I might be wrong, because that's not a situation I normally run into) the compiler processes one file at a time and it's perfectly legal to have something declared but not defined (after all it could be defined in another file) **at the compiling stage**

The linker puts all the files togetherm so if a symbol is used (called, in your case) and it isn't defined, he is definitely going to complain.

HTH

Comment: I probably detailled a lot of things you already know, but it might be useful for someone else, who knows ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not linking with the SDL framework or library (however it comes packaged).

In Xcode, click on your project (top of the files tree view), then your Target. Then click the Summary tab. That's where you'd add the SDL framework.

(If it comes as a .lib, you need to add an extra flag to the linker, such as "-lsdl").

Linking with SDL should take care of your unresolved externals.